# ActiveModel::Serializers Gem - Versioned API Namespacing Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I'm new to Rails and Modules/Namespaces

My Controller is namespaced like this:

```
module Api
  module V1
   class PostsController < ApiController
```

And ActiveModel::Serializers put a "Serializers" folder in my app folder, and in it, I've created post_serializer.rb containing the following code:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :body, :category, 
end
```

When I try to access the JSON response I get:

```
NameError at /api/v1/posts
uninitialized constant Api::V1::PostsController::PostSerializer
```

What is the problem here and what is the best way to Namespace my Serializers alongside my API versions?

Comment: Be sure to restart your server after configuring serializer.

Restarting the server with `rails restart` was not working in my case, but restarting with ctrl+c on server terminal worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

be aware that namespaces should match the folder structure:

```
# should be in app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb
module Api
  module V1
   class PostsController < ApiController

# should be in app/serializers/post_serializer.rb
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
```

when using `PostSerializer` without a prefix, the current namespace is assumed. if you are referencing the global namespace use `::PostSerializer`

Comment: It's worth noting that ActiveModel Serializers really don't like to be namespaced, this is because the serializers are paired with the models (not the views or endpoints), and models are not typically versioned. I'm not sure I agree with the decision, but thats what the core team has decided.

Comment: @Intentss Interesting, is there any way to namespace them for versioning then?