# ActiveModel Serializer won't look up serializer class implicitly, to get json serialized correctly the serializer has to be explicitly passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I'm having an issue in my Rails 4.2.6 project with ActiveModel Serializers (v0.10.2). The issue I'm having is if no serializer is passed to the render call in the controller, rails won't use any serializer and render the object as it would normally. However, passing it the serializer class name works as expected.

```
render json: @tag  # renders the whole object as if just to_json was called
render json: @tag, serializer: API::V1::TagSerializer # renders it correctly through the serializer
```

Currently, the controller this is in a versioned api namespace `API::V1::Tags`

I have a action_model_serializers initializer, and it's contents are:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
ActiveModelSerializers.config.key_transform = :camel_lower
ActiveModelSerializers.config.serializer_lookup_enabled = true
```

And my serializer located in `app/serializers/api/v1/tag_serializer.rb`:

```
class API::V1::TagSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at

  has_many :taggings, serializer: API::V1::TaggingSerializer

  link :self do
    api_v1_tag_url(object, host: 'localhost:3000')
  end
end
```

I'm not quite sure what is wrong, I have tried restarting everything, I have included `ActionController::Serialization` in my application controller, nothing I try works.

Unsure if this is a related problem, but even after added `include: 'taggings'` to the render function, and the `has_many :taggings, serializer: API::V1::TaggingSerializer` in the serializer, the only thing being rendered in the relationships is the tagging id and `type: 'taggings'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , and I was also doing name spacing. I think [this answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464369/2420206) are still relevant

As I really did want to namespace my serializers (api:v1) so I could swap in new serializers in the next version, I just kept the explicit call. If there is a better answer I would love to hear about it